How to consume data of 1 column based on other column
I have a sheet with 4k records and need to consume data before importing to the system and face a problem with Excel formula since I'm not familiar with it.
How can I consume data from Dosage column (B) based on Medicine column (A), my expected result should be like G or H (any of Result 1 or 2 is fine).


For result 2 use =UNIQUE(A2:B15).

Does the different dosage also mean they may be different compound?

@P.b , just due to the origin data is messy

GROUPBY() is perfect function for this case.
=GROUPBY(A1:A15,B1:B15,LAMBDA(x,ARRAYTOTEXT(UNIQUE(x))),3,0)

If you do not have access to GROUPBY() then try-
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A15),MAP(UNIQUE(A2:A15),
LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B15,A2:A15=x))))))



For result 2, simply use UNIQUE() function.
=UNIQUE(A2:B15)


